# Does a "windows keyboard" on bootcamp installed windows work as if on a normal PC (hotkeys etc.)?

Tags: keyboard, bootcamp, windows, ms-office

I do want to use windows on my Mac especially due to the low hotkey functionality of Excel and PowerPoint on Mac.

Therefore I also want to use a windows keyboard. My question is: If I install windows via bootcamp and connect a normal (windows) keyboard. Does it work like a normal PC or are there some  problems I should be aware of?

This is basically the only way I can avoid buying a second notebook so help is greatly appreciated.

I do think that it will not work on a virtual machine since some hotkeys (for instance switching between windows) are still linked to the underlying operating system. Therefore I think bootcamp is the way to go.

I did not find any previous questions regarding this problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose the keyboard from within Windows 10. You should be able to choose a standard Windows keyboard when installing Windows. The rest of this answer assumes Windows 10 is already installed.

This answer was tested using Windows 10 Pro version 1909.

### To add a new keyboard layout on Windows 10, use these steps:

1. Open Settings.
2. Click on Time & Language.
3. Click on Language.
4. Under the "Preferred languages" section, select the current default language. In my case, this is `English (United States) - US`.
5. Click the Options button.
6. Under the "Keyboards" section, click the Add a keyboard button. ...
7. Select the new keyboard layout. In my case this is `US QWERTY`.

The result should appear as shown below.

[image]

Note: You may encounter the opposite, where the Windows keyboard is installed and the Apple keyboard is not.

### How to choose the Windows keyboard as default.

1. Open Settings.
2. Click on Time & Language.
3. Click on Language.
4. Under the "Preferred languages" section, select the `Choose an input method to always use as default`.
5. In the pulldown under "Override the default input method" section, choose `English (United States) - US`.

The result should appear as shown below.

[image]

### References

[How to the change keyboard layout on Windows 10](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-change-your-keyboard-layout-windows-10)
[Switch between languages using the Language bar](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/switch-between-languages-using-the-language-bar-1c2242c0-fe15-4bc3-99bc-535de6f4f258)
[Use your Apple Keyboard in Windows with Boot Camp](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202676)
[Use function keys on a Mac keyboard in Windows with Boot Camp](https://support.apple.com/guide/bootcamp-control-panel/use-function-keys-on-a-mac-keyboard-bcmp423a8bcd/mac)